# Laravel Passport oauth/token route not calling issue Token method

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

i have a problem in laravel passport.
i installed passport successfully. im using below code to get token

```
Route::post('/oauth/token', [
    'uses' => '\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken',
]);
```

but when i test this by postman it return`s error 500 and show no error, just blank page.
**of course it works on local.** i have uploaded my site on server and configured it. when i test it on server, this error happens.
please help me thank you.

Comment: Check your server error log, basically 500 error indicates the problem at server side and it might be the configuration issue not sure, you need to check your error log first.

Comment: there is no log about this :|

Comment: Solved. it was for version of php. after update server, it`s working right